# how do i split message into 2 properties based on one of 2 tokens?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-file

I think this is a simple case, but I have been having issues implementing it.

My input message is in the format:  `aaaaaaaaa;bbbbbbbbbb` or `aaaaaaa:bbbbbbb` and what i was trying to do was to split on either of the colon or semicolon, and then assign them to key and value pairs.

I was doing 2 mutates but it was erroring on that when I ran some sample tests.

```
mutate{
  split => {
    "message" => ":"
  }
  add_field => {
    "key" => "%{[message][0]}"
    "value" => "%{[message][1]}"
  }
}
mutate{
  split => {
    "message" => ";"
  }
  add_field => {
    "key" => "%{[message][0]}"
    "value" => "%{[message][1]}"
  }
}
```

but i dont think that was right.  I was then looking more into grok but wasnt sure if that was how it works.

Should I instead be doing:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{key}:%{value}" }
  }
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{key};%{value}" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that using grok. Try this:

```
grok { match => { "message" => "%{DATA:field1}[:;]%{GREEDYDATA:field2}" } }
```

Comment: ill take a look as see if that works.  I was not sure if the match string was a regex or if there are specific conditions for it.  Ill check it out and then get back to you. :)